# Confidence intervals for the MTTF in survival analysis in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival-analysis, weibull

I have to assess the MTTF of electrical devices in presence of radiation, for different test conditions (voltage).
For each voltage, I can only test few units (typically 5), the number of units failing ranges from 0 (at low voltages) to possibly 5 (at high voltages).
Therefore, it is a case of survival analysis with possibly very high "right" censoring (for example, at the end of irradiation, only one unit may have failed and the other 4 ones will be OK). I'm not a statistician, so I'd like to ask for advice.

I'm using R and the "survival" package to handle the data. According to what I've understood, R computes the Kaplan-Meier estimator and tries to fit the resulting empirical distribution to a Weibull failure model (I'm using survreg with dist="weibull", which is the failure model of such devices)

My problem:

I can compute a MTTF (I use the mean of the Weibull distribution with the parameters resulting from the Weibull fit), but I'm a bit lost to get the 95% confidence interval of the MTTF.
The vcov() function applied to the return of survreg(...) provides variance and covariance on the Weibull parameters, but I think there is an additional uncertainty due to the Kaplan-Meier estimator (see: Greenwood's formula) that is not integrated to the whole thing.

I do not know how to put all the pieces together; are there facilities in R (in the survival package or elsewhere) to achieve this? Or could you please provide guidelines on how to integrate all error sources?

Comment: How about `tolerance::exttol.int` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks, this might help! However, after reading the help of exttol.int, I cannot see what would be the x parameter. For instance, if I have 2 deaths and 3 right censored points, applying the Kaplan-Meier estimator results in me having three (time, probality) pairs of data. The exttol.int example in the documentation uses 1-dimensional randomly (weibull) distributed points, not 2-d points...

Comment: The foundation of my issue is: "How to compute with R a 95% CI for the MTTF of a survival experiment, given the uncertainties in the Kaplan-Meier estimator AND the uncertainties in the fitting procedure (Weibull)?" Please do not hesitate to edit and/or ask questions if the formulation of the problem seems wrong or inadequate.